# Rails: Disable/Remove the "session" functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is a way to disable or remove the "session" functionality from Rails.

I use my own, database-stored sessions, and don't want to introduce potential bugs by having the built in sessions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be possible by simply removing the middlewares that provides the session functionality:

```
# config/application.rb
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::Flash
```

But note that some gems may not work without the session, though. Unless you've orchestrated a workaround for those or you're not using such gems.

Answer (score 0):

Rails' Documentation stated this:

> Sessions are lazily loaded. If you don't access sessions in your
>   action's code, they will not be loaded. Hence you will never need to
>   disable sessions, just not accessing them will do the job.

if you really want to disable the session oreoluwa statements will do the job.